# Swift: How can I pass data from child viewcontroller prepareForSegue to change the TextLabel of a cell of parent viewcontroller tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I pass data from child viewcontroller prepareForSegue to change Title of a cell of parent viewcontroller tableview?

I have done it this way, but I don't think it's right:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 

{
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCreateTask" {
        let contact = contactList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row]

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateTaskVC

        destinationVC.tableView.reloadData()

        if let destinationCell = destinationVC.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("assignToCell") as? UITableViewCell {
            destinationCell.textLabel?.text = contact.contactName
            destinationCell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.contactEmail
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working and you don't think it's the best way or is it not working?

Comment: Your code is asking for a cell from the table view's cache.  Assuming it gets one, it could be any cell that's not currently in use.  How would you decide which cell you really want to update?

Comment: if you push to the parent vc, it ok to use `segue.destinationController`. If you are doing a pop (back button for instance) maybe is more reasonable a delegate.

Comment: Sorry, but can't we just use delegates here? Triggered on viewDidLoad or so?

Comment: There really is no need for delegation - unwind segues were designed for just this purpose.

Comment: @DantePuglisi -  yes it's working, but I don't think it's the best way. phillipmills - by using the cell identifier. Stuart - I am using an unwind segue, but how do I reference the data?

Answer (score 0):

Your child view controller should not know about the implementation of its parent. You are reaching into the table view of the parent from the child, but it would be more correct for the parent to access the required data from the child. Unwind segues allow you to do this by defining an unwind method in the parent.

**In your parent**, you define an `@IBAction` method that takes a single `UIStoryboardSegue` parameter. This is called on the parent at the start of the segue, and allows you to "pass back" any data to the parent in a way that prevents the need for delegation. A `UIStoryboardSegue` has a `sourceViewController` property, so in the case of an unwind segue, the child is the source.

```
@IBAction func unwindToParent(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let childVC = segue.sourceViewController as? ChildVC {
        // update this VC (parent) using newly created data from child
    }
}
```

After defining the method, you create the segue in your storyboard by control-dragging from the triggering element in your child scene to the "exit" icon at the top of that scene. From the menu that appears, choose the unwind action you just created in the parent.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think I get how it should be implemented now, but just to be clear, how can I reference the data from the child prepareforsegue?

Comment: Expose an API on the child through which the _parent_ can access the data from its unwind action. For example, expose a 'selectedContact' variable on your child, then in the unwind method the parent can get at that contact object and use it to set the required table view cell's label text.